# How to change the background color of an ant.design InputNumber?

Tags: reactjs, antd

[image]

```
<InputNumber
    min={13}
    max={125}
    defaultValue={this.props.defaultValue}
    style={{
        width: this.props.width,
        borderColor: this.props.colorTheme.text6Color, <= Working
        backgroundColor: this.props.colorTheme.text7Color, <= edits the rectangle behind the white rectangle with circle edges
        background: this.props.colorTheme.text7Color, <= Not working
        color: this.props.colorTheme.keyText3Color <= Not working
    }}
/>
```

How can I style the back of the InputNumber?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using plain CSS?

If you just want to change the color, you may try:

`backgroundColor: this.props.colorTheme.text7Color`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
style={{backgroundColor: this.props.colorTheme.text7Color}}
```